# Building C/C++ projects with ASM modules in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, assembly, masm

I'm feeling like an eejit right now. I have been using Visual Studio 2010 Professional successfully for C/C++ projects for quite some time. But now I have a project that also includes a couple of ASM files (written for the Microsoft Assembler).  I read a few articles about enabling MASM in Visual Studio. I followed the instructions for checking the boxes for MASM and MASM64 in the project's Build Customizations. Then I saved the Project and reopened it. But now it cannot load the project and gives this error message:

*The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\masm64.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.*

Where do I find this masm64.targets file or how do I create it? It is not anywhere on the disk.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

A tip for anyone who runs into the same problem, I found masm64.targets on GitHub:
https://github.com/MMOCOM/OSIE-GF/blob/master/Rules/masm64.targets